# How can I move existing tab to Firefox container?

Tags: firefox, tabs

I'm testing new Firefox [container feature](https://testpilot.firefox.com/experiments/containers) but can't seem to find how to move existing tabs to a specific container.

Is open blank tab in said container then pasting URL the only solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tabs can be assigned to containers via:

**Mouse**

[`Switch Container`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switch-container/) adds a toolbar icon which gives a list of the containers from which to select.

**Keyboard**

[`Search and Switch Containers`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-and-switch-containers/) allows you to switch the current tab's container by going to to the location bar and typing:

```
co <container name>
```

Comment: I have been using _Switch container_ for a few months and it's damn simple and to the point. Didn't knew about _Search and Switch Containers_ excellent for power user!

Answer (score 4):

The container can not be changed for existing tabs, it can only be assigned when creating new tabs. There is an enhancement request filed for that, [bug 1323873](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323873), maybe you could leave a comment there describing your precise use-case to show interest in that feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-open an existing tab in a container by doing the following.

1. Right click the tab
2. Select `Reopen in Container`
3. Select the container name
4. Celebrate your new found sense of security!